# Object Consistency when updating shape attributes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm very new to D3 and Javascript, so forgive me if my code looks a little ugly or poorly organized.

I have been working on a plot that utilizes 3 metrics: an x and y axis, and the radius of the circle as a data metric for the plot. The data I am reading is a two dimensional array, with each row being a different metric, and each column being a new data point. I have successfully implemented a method to change the radius of the circle dynamically by picking a different metric from a drop box, but this was after struggling endlessly with a very particular issue - my data was being assigned to the wrong circle!

When I initially create my circles, I first use sort() to sort the circles in descending order from the default radius metric (in my code, its "impactcpu"). This was done to fix an issue where larger circles that were drawn after smaller circles were obstructing the smaller circles, so I wanted to "paint" the largest circles first.

I was able to get past this issue by first sorting my calculated data array before assignign it to the circles, which preserved the default order. However, I am now trying to do something similar with my X and Y axis. While my dropdown menu is correctly assigning metric values to circles, it is doing so to the WRONG circles. I have yet to figure out a solution to this issue, as re-sorting the array before assignign is like I was doing for the radius isn't working (which I expected). Are there any suggestions as to how I could ensure the right data point is assigned to the correct circle? Preferably one that wouldn't require an overhaul of the rest of my code :)

Please take a look at my jsfiddle for an example of my above situation:

http://jsfiddle.net/kingernest/YDQR4/3/

Example of how I am creating my circles initially:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset, function(d) { return d.id })
    .enter()    
    .append("circle")
    .sort(function(a, b){    //Sort by radius size, helps reduce obstruction of circles
        return d3.descending(a[14], b[14]);
    })
    .attr("cx", function(d){ //x axis is Req IO, col index 9
        return xScale(d[9]);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ //y axis is Req CPU, col index 8
        return yScale(d[8]);
    })
    .attr("r", function(d){ //radius is based off Impact CPU, col 14

        console.log("Rad: " + d[14])
        return d[14] * 1.5;
    })
    .attr("class", "dataCircle")
```

etc

How I am currently altering my radius:

```
function changeRad() {
     console.log(this.value); 
     var myRadData = [];
     var index = metricHash[this.value];
     var weight; //to adjust data to fit appropriately in graph
    switch(this.value) 
    {
        case "impactcpu": 
            weight = 1.5;
            break;
        case "spool": 
            weight = .0000001;    //spool is normally a very large value
            break;
        case "pji": 
            weight = 8;
            break;
        case "unnecio": 
            weight = 12;
            break;
        case "duration": 
            weight = .0002;
            break;
        default: alert("Invalid value: " + this.value); 
            break;
    }
     for(var i=0; i < dataset.length; i++)
     {         
         console.log(dataset[i][index]);
         myRadData.push(dataset[i][index] * weight);
     }

    myRadData.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});

    d3.selectAll("circle")
        .data(myRadData)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .attr("r", function(d){
            return d;
        });

    circles.data(dataset); //reassign old data set (with all data values)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things I see with your code:

1. Inconsistent key function on your data binding - you correctly use it on your initial creation of the circles(`.data(dataset, function(d) { return d.id })`), but do not reference it when updating them, adding the same key on the updates will make sure that you are updating the same elements.
2. DOM sorting - Your use of selection.sort when initially creating your circles seems logical and appropriate(`.sort(function(a, b){ return d3.descending(a[14], b[14]); })`) I would recommending extending this to your update functions, rather than re-binding data.

I have made these quick updates to your code and it appears to solve your issues:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbHfk/3/

Comment: Josh, Thanks for the advice. I started to experiment with the keys after making my initial post yesterday, after reading the following article:

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/

However, I didn't get to finish implementing the change before I stopped working on the project. But thank you very much for your advice. Keys were the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I grasp your entire code (it's quite long), but I think the solution lies along these lines:

1 - When you initially create the circles, use a keys function. Good, you're doing this:

```
.data(dataset, function(d) { return d.id; })
```

2 - Give the circles an ID attribute using the same function:

```
.attr("ID", function(d) { return d.id; })
```

3 - Then when you need to modify a particular circle individually you can select it like so:

```
svg.select('#' + myCircleID).attr('blahblah', somevalue)
```

I also notice that you've lost the ID attribute as you build up the myRadData array. This will prevent the code from joining them to the correct circles. Since you have an ID attribute at the beginning, you're better off using the keys function throughout, rather than trying to use sorting to make things line up.

If you want a more specific answer I think you need to boil the example down to the simplest possible form that reproduces the issue.